# Repository URL in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-plugin

I am new to Scala, I have downloaded sbt 1.x into Windows, and configured necessary system variable.

In our organization, nexus is being used as repository URL. When I launch sbt 1st time , it fails as it's not able to connect default repository url. Please provide me necessary steps to be taken to point to my client nexus repository.

I tried from documentation, but it didn't solve my issue.

Comment: may be the organization repository might require username and password. Please ensure you have configure that

Comment: You should add relevant parts of your `build.sbt` to the question

Answer (score 0):

Add the nexus url (and some name) to sbt.boot.properties as described [here](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Launcher-Configuration.html) (section [repositories]).